# Non-induction proof that for $n\geq m\geq 3$, $m\cdot n^m>(n+1)^m$

Tags: inequality

> $n\geq m\geq 3$, prove $m\cdot n^m>(n+1)^m$.

I will use mathematical induction to prove, would like to know another proof

Comment: Rewrite it as $1+\frac{1}{n}< m^{\frac{1}{m}}$.  Then you just need to show that $1+\frac{1}{m}<m^{\frac{1}{m}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(n+1)^m=n^m\Bigl(1+{1\over n}\Bigr)^m<n^m\bigl(e^{1/n}\bigr)^m\leq e\ n^m<m\ n^m$$

Comment: (-1) This is not a solution, since you used unproved inequality $(1+1/n)<e^{1/n}$

Comment: @Norbert: $1+x\leq e^x$ is a standard calculus fact. The OP did ask for a "non inductive proof"; he didn't ask for an injection $[n+1]^m\to[m]\times[n]^m$.

Comment: I think OP asked for the proof from the first principles. It is better to ask OP, until then (-1)

Answer (score 2):

This condition is equivalent to the condition that $m > ({1 + 1/n})^m$. As $n \geq m$, the following condition implies this:

$m > ({1+1/m})^m$.

In other words,

$m^{m+1} > ({m+1})^m$

or $m^{1/m} > ({m+1})^{1/({m+1})}$

Consider the function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$.

Consider $g(x) = log(f(x)) = \frac{1}{x} log(x)$

$g'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}(1-log(x))$, which is $0$ only at $x = e$. We can easily check this is a maximum (by differentiating again, etc). So for $m \geq 3$, as $m \geq e$, $g(m) > g(m+1)$. So $f(m) > f(m+1)$. This proves the claim.